# can we talk about zero sets of rational functions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Usually, when talking about algebraic sets of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$, we refer to zero sets of collections of polynomials in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, where $k$ is the underlying field.

Question: how can we talk formally about zero sets of rational functions, i.e. zero sets of collections of elements of $\mathbb{R}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$? I am asking this, because i am working with some algebraic set $S$ and i want to remove from $S$ all points satisfying the equation $f(x)=0$, where $f$ is polynomial and what i want to say is that $S -Z(f) = Z\left((I_S)_f\right)$, where $Z(\cdot)$ is the zero set operator. How can i formalize this (what is missing is that i have not seen $Z(\cdot)$ taking arguments rational functions).

Comment: If you are studying rational functions over reals, you might find this paper useful http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3800 . It shows how you can define Zariski-like topology on reals using rational functions. The paper is in french though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aren't they equivalent? Consider the rational function $$R(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \dfrac{f(x_1, \dots, x_n)}{g(x_1, \dots, x_n)}$$ where $f, g$ are polynomials with no common factors. Then $$R(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0.$$

**Added Later:** As mrf wisely pointed out, the two sides are not exactly the same. However, if we restrict $f$ to the complement of $g^{-1}(0)$, then the equivalence remains true. Note, this is not a strange thing to do as $R$ is already restricted to this set.

Comment: Not quite equivalent. Would you say that $(0,0)$ is in the zero set of $x_1/x_2$?

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly define a topology on $k^n$ where you let your closed sets be zeroes of rational functions, this topology will be completely equivalent to the topology of $\mathbb A^n$ and furthermore the nice algebraic correspondence would disappear. As $Z(f) \ne Z(I)$ for any $f \ne 0$, since we are in a field and all non-zero ideals are the unit ideal.

Comment: We will not be inside a field, rather a subring $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]_f$ of the field of quotients of $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.